# How to set up system properties per user?

Tags: playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

We're upgrading to play 2.3.5 and it's the first time I've used the activator.

If I run the activator headless, I can still pass in a bunch of command line flags, but if I try out the new UI I don't know how to pass in overrides for my developer setup (which are different from other developers).   I don't see a way to set unique java properties in a meta activator config that we would exclude from version control.

```
-Dlogger.file=./conf/my-special-logger.xml -Dprop1=special -Dconfig.file=./conf/my-special-file.conf
```

I can symlink `my-special-file.conf` to `application.conf` and get most of what I want.  It's not really an ideal solution and if I leave the symlink in place during bundling, the packager blows up.

```
[error] (*:stage) Duplicate mappings:
[error]     ./my-project/target/universal/stage/conf/my-special-file.conf
[error] from
[error]     ./my-project/conf/application.conf
[error]         ./my-project/conf/my-special-file.conf
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typesafe Activator uses `~/.activator/activatorconfig.txt` as a means of setting Java system properties.

With the following `~/.activator/activatorconfig.txt`:

```
-Dhello=world
```

I could query for the `hello` property in the shell:

```
[play-new-app] $ eval sys.props("hello")
[info] ans: String = world
```

As a reference - this is for Play 2.3.5:

```
[play-new-app] $ dependencies
...
+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| Module                                                     | Required by                                                | Note                                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
...
+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| com.typesafe.play:play_2.11:2.3.5                          | com.typesafe.play:play-ws_2.11:2.3.5                       | As play_2.11-2.3.5.jar                     |
|                                                            | com.typesafe.play:play-jdbc_2.11:2.3.5                     |                                            |
|                                                            | play-new-app:play-new-app_2.11:1.0-SNAPSHOT                |                                            |
|                                                            | com.typesafe.play:play-cache_2.11:2.3.5                    |                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```